# jQuery innerhtml Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I'm using AJAX to return me a complete table that has been generated by a JSP (using Spring MVC). However, this doesn't seem to work. I tried at first just returning a simple list of names with 
 elements and this executed fine, but it won't let me insert the table, it just doesn't display anything.

```
function displaySubMenu(niveauId){
    $.get("submenu.htm",{ niveau : niveauId },function(data){
        $('#submenu').html(data);
        $('#submenu').slideDown('slow');
    });
}
```

This ajax request returns me a table like the one here :http://pastebin.com/7BGFLPH2

**Anyone got an idea why this doesn't work and what I should use?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to trace the problem?

E.g.

```
function displaySubMenu(niveauId){
    $.get("submenu.htm",{ niveau : niveauId },function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Does this display the table data?

If so, then $('#submenu') is the problem. I would start by making it visible and avoid all effects until you're sure it's working.

I hope this helps.

Comment: now it slides down and up using the visible selector (so it's invisible normally). I'm sure it returns the table, I can see it in Chrome using the inspector. But it does run fine with just random lines of data and <br /> tags.

Comment: Can you paste the table html that you retrieve to a pastebin website and link it here and do you happen to have some css that may make tables invisible?